# Magento 2 migration Tool: does PRODUCTS model support DELTA (incremental)?

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

when browsing and reading guides it looks like Customers + Orders support incremental data migration (delta: the newly added items) .... bu I also read that this is supported for products : but is this really so?

Somehow it seems it was the plan to support Products Delta migration .... but it never made it through?

Using Magento 2.3.1 : does the 2.3.1 Data Migration Tool support incremental migration for Products?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official document:

*All new or updated entities entered through the Admin panel, like **products and categories**, are not included in incremental migration and will not be migrated.*

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

So, I think delta migration not applicable for product and categories